# how to generate pdf from php file with same css bootstrap layout

Tags: php

I am working on a resume maker project in php, I am fetching all entries from database. so in this project I am using bootstrap for resume designs. I want to add a button to download resume as PDF in same layout as I designed using bootstrap. I have also inserted image of the user. so please help me with specific solution with demo. bootstrap layout is must.

Comment: you need to use pdf libraries for the same like , tcpdf and fpdf and many more. refer this link - http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/create-pdf-documents-online-with-tcpdf/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a library like [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) or [MPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) for that.

As an example, mpdf is really easy to implement:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Here is an [online manual](https://mpdf.github.io/).